# 3D Transformations to HTML5 Youtube videos

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, 3d, youtube

I have applied 3D Transformations to HTML 5 videos (  tag ). I have tried this with sample video files (mp4 format) and works fine. I want to now embed Youtube videos inside the  tag. It seems Youtube HTML 5 videos can be played only by putting it inside a iframe.

If this is correct, can I apply 3D transformations to iframe. I am currently using the Youtube Data APIs to plaI want to do the same to Dailymotion videos.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's just an element.

Use the matrix3d API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/